Why $\theta ([\xi_f, \xi_g])=\frac{1}{2}\xi_f \langle \theta ,\xi_g\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\xi_g \langle \theta ,\xi_f\rangle$?
Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplextic manifold with $\omega =-d\theta$. For $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M)$, we can define a Poisson bracket $\{ f,g\}=\omega (\xi_{f},\xi_f)$ where $i_{\xi_f}\omega=\omega(\xi_f,\cdot )=df$. I have two similar questions:
Why we have $$\theta ([\xi_f, \xi_g])=\frac{1}{2}\xi_f \langle \theta ,\xi_g\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\xi_g \langle \theta ,\xi_f\rangle$$
and $$\{ f,g\} =\frac{1}{2}\xi_f \langle \theta ,\xi_g\rangle -\frac{1}{2}\xi_g \langle \theta ,\xi_f\rangle?$$

The first identity isn't true in general. For example, take $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ with (canonical) coordinates $(q,p)$, $\omega = dq\wedge dp$, and $\theta = p\,dq$. Then $\xi_q = -\frac{\partial}{\partial p}, \xi_p = \frac{\partial}{\partial q}$. So the LHS of the identity (with $f=q, g=p$) is 0, while the RHS is $-\frac{1}{2}$. There must be some other condition you're omitting - where did you see this?
If the first identity is true, the second identity follows from it and the standard identity
$$
d\theta(X,Y) = X(\theta(Y)) - Y(\theta(X)) - \theta([X,Y]).
$$
